# How to list Wikipedia page titles with links using JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, wikipedia-api

This is my current code. It lists out page titles perfectly, but the links all return 'undefined'.

```
function func(json) {
  var e = document.getElementById('wiki');
  var i;
  for (i=0; i < json.query.allpages.length; i++) {
    e.innerHTML += i + ": " + '<a href="' + "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" +  json.query.link+ '">' +  json.query.allpages[i].title + '</a>' + "<br />";
  }
}

function getFromWikipedia() {
  var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
  var e = document.getElementById('wiki');
  var o = document.createElement("script");
      o.setAttribute("src", "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json&apfrom="+txt.value+"&generator=alllinks&callback=func");
  e.appendChild(o);
}
```

Appending "&prop=links" and/or "&generator=alllinks" to the URL doesn't seem to affect the result.

I would like to know what should I include in this portion:

```
'<a href="' + json.query.link+ '">'
```

in order to list the page titles with their respective links.
I have tried "json.query.allpages[i].pageID" and "json.query.alllinks" but it has not been working.

**Edit:**
Gave up on finding URL and went to do the pageid method instead.

Solved it with this:

```
e.innerHTML += i + ": " + '<a href="'+ "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?curid="+  json.query.allpages[i].pageid + '">' +  json.query.allpages[i].title + '</a>' + "<br />";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the link directly using the pageid:

```
function func(json) {
  var e = document.getElementById('wiki');
  var i;
  for (i=0; i < json.query.allpages.length; i++) {
    e.innerHTML += i + ": " + '<a href="' + "http://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=" +  json.query.allpages[i].pageid+ '">' +  json.query.allpages[i].title + '</a>' + "<br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, for unknown reasons the code does not work (nothing appears when I call the function)- console does not return any error either. I've tried changing the pages to allpages, but the link still appears as undefined.

Comment: (The first empty page is because https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/master/includes/api/ApiQuery.php#L401)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have both `list=` and `generator=` in the same query suggests to me that you don't fully understand how [generators](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) work in the MediaWiki API.

Basically, a generator is a way to use a [list](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Lists) as the source of pages to retrieve [properties](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties) for.  It does *not* make any sense to use a generator as the input to another list query.  That is, you'd normally use `generator=` with `prop=`, *not* with `list=`.  The only reason MediaWiki (seemingly) allows that at all is because:

1. You can make a query with a page list (or a generator) but no `prop=` parameter, [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Foo|Bar).  If you do, you'll just get a minimal default set of properties (title, namespace and page ID) for the pages.
2. You can also combine a properties query and a list query into a single request, [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&titles=Foo|Bar&list=allpages).  You'll just get the results for both queries, merged into the same JSON/XML/etc. output, but they'll be otherwise completely separate.  (You can also make [multiple simultaneous list queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=alllinks|allpages) that way.)

Thus, when you combine a `generator=` with a `list=` query, you'll get both the usual output for the list and a minimal set of properties for the pages matched by the generator.  The two outputs will not be connected in any real way, except for being part of the same API response.

---

Anyway, you wanted to know how to obtain the titles and URLs of all Wikipedia pages with links.  Well, as schudel notes in their answer, to get the URLs for some pages you need `prop=info` with `inprop=url`; to run this query on all linked pages, you can use `generator=alllinks`.  Thus, you end up with:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&inprop=url&generator=alllinks

Note that this gives information about all pages that have links *from* them.  To run the query on all pages with links *to* them, you need to add the parameter `galunique=true`:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&inprop=url&generator=alllinks&galunique=true

(Yes, [this is documented](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Alllinks), although not as clearly as it perhaps could be.)

Obviously, the link targets will include a lot of missing pages.  The fact that the link *sources* seemingly also include a missing page with an empty title is presumably due to a faulty record in Wikipedia's link database.  This could be fixed by rebuilding the (redundant) links table, but, given Wikipedia's size, this would take quite a bit of time (during which, presumably, the site would have to be locked into read-only mode to avoid further inconsistencies).

---

To process this data in JavaScript, you could do something like this:

```
var apiURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=info&inprop=url&generator=alllinks&callback=myCallback';

function myCallback(json) {
  var e = document.getElementById('wiki');
  for (var id in json.query.pages) {
    var page = json.query.pages[id];
    if (typeof(page.missing) !== 'undefined') continue;
    e.innerHTML += 
      id + ': <a href="' + escapeHTML(page.fullurl) + '">' + escapeHTML(page.title) + '</a><br />';
  }
  // handle query continuations:
  if (json.continue) {
    var continueURL = apiURL;
    for (var attr in json.continue) {
      continueURL += '&' + attr + '=' + encodeURIComponent(json.continue[attr]);
    }
    doAjaxRequest(continueURL);
}

doAjaxRequest(apiURL + '&continue=');
```

Note that I've also included a basic mechanism for handling [query continuations](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries), since you'll surely need to handle those when using `alllinks`.  Implementing the helper functions `escapeHTML()` and `doAjaxRequest()` is left as an exercise.  Also note that I haven't actually tested this code; I *think* it's OK, but there might be bugs that I've missed.  It will also produce a ridiculously long list, and probably slow your browser to a crawl, simply because Wikipedia has a *lot* of pages.  For a real application, you'd probably want to introduce some kind of an on-demand loading scheme (e.g. only loading more results when the user scrolls down to the end of the current list).